# Can I collect explode then explode again?

Tags: php, laravel, explode, laravel-collection

I'm trying to create data save variable using a text file. I read that the collect function in laravel is the right choice for managing the data.

Here is the data saved after I exploded with PHP_EOL : [image: dd output: exploded variable]

What I want to do is explode once more per array with "|", so my code is like this but it can't.

```
$temps=explode(PHP_EOL,$note);
$isi=collect([
                explode('|',$temps)
            ]);
```

This code can only be applied if it is accompanied by a manual array like this :

```
$isi=collect([
                explode('|',$temps[0]),
                explode('|',$temps[2])
            ]);
```

The dd output: [image: dd output: manual array]

Comment: you can loop through them and explode 1 by 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I think you've worked out, [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) returns an array but accepts a string, so you can't pass the result of `explode` directly to another `explode` call.

Instead you need to get each individual string in the array produced by the first `explode`, and `explode` each one separately.

Clearly it's not practical to try and hard-code a reference to each item of the array (as per your attempt), so instead you can use a loop to fetch each item, or a slightly neater way is to use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), like in the following example:

```
function pipeExplode($str)
{
    return explode("|", $str);
}

$text = "sdlkfjsdl|kwflwerflwekr|wlkjlgk4w\n3rtljhrfgkjed|3jhkrjghd|4t44thj\n33rtlhwege|3rth3herjgke|hkjfgdf";
$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);

$finalArr = array_map('pipeExplode', $arr);
print_r($finalArr);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/EM6Ct

This will take each string from the first array, pass it through the `pipeExplode` function to get a new array back from that, and then add that array back into the outer array which is returned by the `array_map` function.